# confirmation popup message (ASP.NET/VB)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, popup, confirm

I want to have a confirmation message box pop up when a user clicks the cancel button on a form. I believe this would be the correct javascript code:

```
function confirmation() {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel? Any information you have entered will be discarded.")
        if (answer) {
            window.location = "index.htm";
        }
    }
```

But, I'm not sure how I can call the function with VB from my code behind page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your cancel button add this markup attribute

```
OnClientClick="return confirmation();"
```

Comment: Doesn't work...    <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" Width="100%" DisplaySideBar="false" OnActiveStepChanged="Wizard1_ActiveStepChanged" OnFinishButtonClick="Wizard1_FinishButtonClick" DisplayCancelButton="true" OnCancelButtonClick="return confirmation();"> it throws an error because "'return' is not a member of 'ASP.courseapprovalrequest_aspx'."

Comment: Not sure if that's what you meant?

Comment: Try adding 'OnCancelButtonClientClick' attribute instead of 'OnClick'

Comment: In wizard control case what about adding a button with text equals to cancel, and set onClientClick

Comment: Oh that works great. Thanks! I didn't realize it was that simple.